# Fixed Thead; Scrollable Tbody ~ Righter Columns Less Aligned

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

After reading many posts about having a fixed theader with a scrollabe tbody, most answers point to adjusting the tbody to display: block. However, display block makes my columns on the righter side have a skewed alignment the further right the column goes. I am dealing with dynamic data so sometimes my table is rendered with 16 columns, but sometimes it could be up to 25 columns. I want all the columns aligned properly, while maintaining a fixed thead with a scrollable tbody. Here is my CSS:

```
table {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 810px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

thead,
tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th {
}

td {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

tr th {
  flex: 1;
}

tr td {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here is a small Codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMmqxK

The Codepen skew is less prominent than the skew on my website, so it's a bit hard to notice. Any help would be much appreciated. If I posted a screenshot you would be able to see the problem more, however, I cannot due to a corporate envrionment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that the `<th>`s are `text-align:center` but the `<td>`s are `text-align:left`. This is why the skew increase when there is more space in each column.

Easiest solution is to remove `padding-left: 10px` from `<tbody>` *(only included in your CopePen)* and set `<td>`s to `text-align: center`.

If you need to have left-aligned `<td>`s then you can do the reverse and set your `<th>`s to `text-align:left`.

Comment: It's not that. I think by defualt th and td tags are text-align: center. Even if they weren't, I've tried you solution and there is still skew. I think it has to do with the right  scroll bar taking up space.